# py2neo Batch Insert timing out for even 2k nodes

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm just trying to do a simple batch insert test for 2k nodes and this is timing out. I'm sure it's not a memory issue because I'm testing with a ec2 xLarge instance and I changed the neo4j java heap and datastore memory parameters. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you batch insert with fewer number of nodes ? Is your http client closing the connection ? Do you use streaming ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an existing bug with large batches due to Python's handling of the server streaming format. There will be a fix for this released in version 1.5 in a few weeks' time.

Comment: Okay, looking forward to it!

Comment: Hey, great stuff. I can definitely insert mode nodes with the batch inserter. I seem to be getting system errors north of 50k nodes. Is there something I should be checking in this case?

Comment: Nevermind, it was a heapspace error that I didn't deal with on my part. Keep up the great work!

Comment: Good to know - thanks for feeding back. Incidentally, the new version was released a few days ago containing the previously mentioned fix.

Answer (score 0):

Can you inserting by 300 nodes by one batch insert?

For example:

```
nodes_to_insert = []
for n in my_nodes:
    nodes_to_insert.append(n)
    if len(nodes_to_insert) == 300:
        func_insert_by_batch(nodes_to_insert)
        nodes_to_insert = []
if nodes_to_insert:
    func_insert_by_batch(nodes_to_insert)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey so apparently there are some bugs associated with neo4j version 1.8.X, which was what I was using. The below link may provide light support.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/neo4j/Nqc9g1FZSD8

EDIT: nevermind, upgrading didn't help.